# Spring MVC + Hivernate + JQGrid - Exception - HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, exception, jqgrid

I am trying to implement jqgrid in my project. However, I am receiving following exception while running the application. Not able to resolve the error. Some help is appreciated. My project is Spring MVC + Hibernate + JQGrid.

```
type Exception report

message Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)


root cause
java.lang.NumberFormatException: null
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:542)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    com.nej.controller.BranchMstController.getAll(BranchMstController.java:37)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:618)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:57)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:108)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
```

My Controller file is as under where this error is coming branchmstcontroller.java

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package com.nej.controller;

import com.nej.branchmst.model.BranchMst;
import com.nej.branchmst.service.BranchMstService;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

/**
 *
 * @author Tushar
 */
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value={"/admin/branchmstmgmt"})
public class BranchMstController {

    @Autowired
    private BranchMstService branchmstService;

     @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)         
     public @ResponseBody  BranchmstResponse getAll(HttpServletRequest request){
         int rows = 0;
         rows = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rows"));
         int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
         String sidx = request.getParameter("sidx");
         String sord = request.getParameter("sord");
         List<BranchMst> list = null;
         list = branchmstService.getBranchMsts(rows, page, sidx, sord);
         BranchmstResponse response = new BranchmstResponse();
         response.setRows(list);
         int count = branchmstService.getNoOfRecords();
         int total = count%rows == 0 ? (int)Math.ceil(count/rows) : (int)Math.ceil(count/rows)+1;
         response.setTotal(total);
         response.setRecords(count);
         response.setPage(page);
         return response;
     }

     @RequestMapping(value="/edit")         
     public ModelAndView doEdit(HttpServletRequest request){
         Byte brcmpcode = 0;
         Integer brcode = 0;
         String brname = null, bradd1 = null, bradd2 = null, brcity = null, brpin = null;
         String bremail = null, brcontactperson = null, oper = null;

         Enumeration<String> paramNames = request.getParameterNames();
         while(paramNames.hasMoreElements()){
             String s = paramNames.nextElement();
             if("brcode".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 brcode = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("brcode"));
             }else if("brcmpcode".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 brcmpcode = Byte.parseByte(request.getParameter("brcmpcode"));
             }else if("brname".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 brname = request.getParameter("brname");
             }else if("bradd1".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 bradd1 = request.getParameter("bradd1");
             }else if("bradd2".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 bradd2 = request.getParameter("bradd2");
             }else if("brcity".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 brcity = request.getParameter("brcity");
             }else if("brpin".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 brpin = request.getParameter("brpin");
             }else if("bremail".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 bremail = request.getParameter("bremail");
             }else if("brcontactperson".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 brcontactperson = request.getParameter("brcontactperson");
             }else if("oper".equalsIgnoreCase(s)){
                 oper = request.getParameter("oper");
             }
         }
        Map<String, String> model = new HashMap<String, String>();
         if("edit".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
             BranchMst branchmst = new BranchMst();
             branchmst.setBrCmpcode(brcmpcode);
             branchmst.setBrcode(brcode);
             branchmst.setBrname(brname);
             branchmst.setBradd1(bradd1);
             branchmst.setBradd2(bradd2);
             branchmst.setBrcity(brcity);
             branchmst.setBrpin(brpin);
             branchmst.setBremail(bremail);
             branchmst.setBrcontactperson(brcontactperson);
             branchmstService.updateBranchMst(branchmst);
         }else if("add".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
             BranchMst branchmst = branchmstService.getBranchMst(brcode);
             if(branchmst == null){
                branchmst = new BranchMst();
                branchmst.setBrCmpcode(brcmpcode);
                branchmst.setBrcode(brcode);
                branchmst.setBrname(brname);
                branchmst.setBradd1(bradd1);
                branchmst.setBradd2(bradd2);
                branchmst.setBrcity(brcity);
                branchmst.setBrpin(brpin);
                branchmst.setBremail(bremail);
                branchmst.setBrcontactperson(brcontactperson);
                branchmstService.saveBranchMst(branchmst);
             }else{
                 throw new RuntimeException();
             }
         }else if("del".equalsIgnoreCase(oper)){
             branchmstService.deleteBranchMst(brcode);
         }
         return new ModelAndView("branchmstmgmt",model);
     }    

}
```

The relevant JSP file is as below : branchmstmgmt.jsp

```
<%-- 
    Document   : branchmstmgmt
    Created on : Sep 13, 2014, 3:01:07 PM
--%>

<%@taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page session="true"%>

<tiles:insertDefinition name="defaultTemplate">
    <tiles:putAttribute name="body"> 


<%@page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/pure-0.4.2.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/jquery-ui.css"/>

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/jquery-ui.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/styles/ui.jqgrid.css" />
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/grid.locale-en.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/script/js-for-branchmst.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  


 <body>
 <table id="list" class="scroll"></table>
 <div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
 </body>
 </html> 
    </tiles:putAttribute>
</tiles:insertDefinition>
```

The .js file where the JQGrid has been implemented is as below: js-for-branchmst.js

```
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

var row_selected;

 $(document).ready(function(){ 
         $("#list").jqGrid({ 
             datatype: 'json', 
             mtype: 'GET', 
             height: 'auto',
             url:'/admin/branchmstmgmt',
             editurl:'/admin/branchmstmgmt/edit',
             colNames:['Company','Branch','Branch Name','Address-1','Address-2','City','Pin','E-Mail','Contact Person'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'brcmpcode',index:'brcmpcode', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brcode',index:'brcode', width:50, editable:true, editrules:{required:true,number:true}, editoptions:{size:10}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brname',index:'brname', width:100, editable:true, editrules:{required:true}, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'bradd1',index:'bradd1', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30, maxlength:"60"}, edittype:'textarea'},
                    {name:'bradd2',index:'bradd2', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brcity',index:'brcity', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{size:20}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brpin',index:'brpin', width:50, editable:true, editoptions:{size:20}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'bremail',index:'bremail', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}},
                    {name:'brcontactperson',index:'brcontactperson', width:100, editable:true, editoptions:{size:30}, formoptions:{elmprefix:'*'}}
                ],
             gridview: true,
             toolbar: [false, "bottom"],
             pager: $('#pager'), 
             rowNum:3, 
             rowList:[1,2,3], 
             sortname: 'brcode', 
             sortorder: "asc", 
             viewrecords: true,
             altRows: false, 
             jsonReader : {
                 root: "rows",
                 page: "page",
                 total: "total",
                 records: "records",  
                 repeatitems: false
                },        
             imgpath: 'themes/basic/images', 
             caption: 'My JQGrid App',
             onSelectRow: function(row_id){
                             if(row_id !== null) {
                                 row_selected = row_id;
                                 }
                             }
     }); 

     $("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:false,refresh:false},
             { 
               beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#brcode',form).hide();}
             },
             { 
              beforeShowForm: function(form) {$('#brcode',form).show();}
             },
             {
             }
             );
 });

 $.jgrid.edit = {
     addCaption: "Add Branch Master",
     editCaption: "Edit Branch Master",
     bSubmit: "Submit",
     bCancel: "Cancel",
     bClose: "Close",
     bYes : "Yes",
     bNo : "No",
     bExit : "Cancel",
     closeAfterAdd:true,
     closeAfterEdit:true,
     reloadAfterSubmit:true,
     msg: {
             required: "is mandatory or required",
             number: "is a number field. Enter a valid number",
             minValue: "should not be less than ",
             maxValue: "should not be more than "
             },
     errorTextFormat: function (response) {
         if (response.status !== 200) {
             return "Error encountered while processing. Please check the accuracy of data entered.";
         }
     },

     afterSubmit : function(response,postdata) {
                         return(true,"ok");
                         }  
 };

 $.jgrid.del = {
     caption: "Delete Branch Master",
     msg: "Delete selected Branch?",
     bSubmit: "Delete",
     bCancel: "Cancel",
     reloadAfterSubmit:true,
     closeOnEscape:true,
     onclickSubmit : function(eparams) {
                             var rowData = $("#list").jqGrid('getRowData', row_selected);
                             var retarr = {'brcode':rowData['brcode']};
                             return retarr;
                             }    
 };
```

I can interpret from the exception is that response object is not properly returning "rows" parameter, but not able to resolve it. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

That exception is thrown from Integer.parseInt so parameter rows or page is probably null. 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)

Update:
This is where it goes wrong

```
rows = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("rows"));
int page = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("page"));
```

The easiest is if you change to map the request parameters automatically

```
public @ResponseBody  BranchmstResponse getAll(
    @RequestParam(value = "rows", required=false) Integer rows, 
    @RequestParam(value = "page", required=false) Integer page, 
    @RequestParam(value = "sidx", required=false) String sidx, 
    @RequestParam(value = "sord", required=false) String sord, 
    HttpServletRequest request){
    // if (rows == null) ...
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I am not able to resolve why it is returning null, where my code is doing wrong!

Comment: I have changed the BranchMstController as per your suggestion, as expected I am getting null values for all four parameters i.e. rows, page, sidx, sord. I am not able to understand why my .jsp is returning these four parameters as null. By inspecting my branchmstmgmt.jsp and js-for-branchmst.js can you suggest the cause of this bug. Further, if I comment out the lines specifying the rows, page, sidx, sord and in place of these if I put hard coded values I don't get any errors, but instead of displaying the page branchmstmgmt.jsp IE asks me to save the file branchmstmgmt.json. Please suggest.

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. Check the network traffic in your browser and make sure that the parameters are set. When you use @ResponseBody it will convert the BranchmstResponse to json automatically. I think that is normal behaviour of ie.

Comment: How do I set the parameters in .jsp file

Comment: What I mean is just that you should look if the parameters are being sent to the server. Easiest is to look in chrome and network in the developer tools.